# programmable build automation tool?

Tags: build-automation

I'm trying to find a build automation tool (like Apache Ant or Maven), where build script is written in an OOP language (for example Java, or Ruby, or something similar). My build process is rather complicated and Ant programming mechanism is not powerful enough to handle it (the script is now very complex and unmaintainable). Can you recommend some?

Answer (score 0):

You could give [Scons](http://www.scons.org/) a try. It's a software construction tool in python (which is an OOP scripting language)

Answer (score 0):

Rake (ruby DSL), Gradle (Groovy) or Buildr (they claim to be a Ruby replacemnt for Maven)?

http://rake.rubyforge.org/

http://www.gradle.org/

http://buildr.apache.org/